# How does google cloud Dataflow read from BigQuery using apache beam?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How are the results read split between the workers? Is one table create with the results of the query and the workers get pages to read from it or does each worker run the query and read different pages or... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from BigQuery, Dataflow actually just calls BigQuery's export API and dumps the table/query to GCS as a bunch of sharded Avro files. Once the files start landing in GCS, the Dataflow workers start reading them in parallel. How the work is distributed i.e. which worker reads which shard/records is abstracted from you and handled/orchestrated by the Dataflow service itself.

Comment: Source please ?

Comment: Stackdriver audit logs. Also, just debug the pipeline and take a look into GCS when it's running. You'll see it happening for yourself.